# Google Maps zoom does not change

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

This is my code:

```
let update = GMSCameraUpdate.zoom(to: 20.0)
mapView.animate(with: update)
print(mapView.camera.zoom)
```

but the zoom is still 4.0, how is it possible? How can I change that?

Answer (score 0):

Try simply animating the zoom itself.

```
mapView.animate(toZoom: 20)
```

Comment: still is 4.0, I'm doing this in view did load, is it a problem?

Comment: Yes, it could be. Don't perform view animations in `viewDidLoad`. Try to do this in `viewDidAppear` instead.